# Azure Certificate Validation Failed By Token Handler

Tags: azure, certificate, x509certificate

I have two client certificates that I have installed for my API project in the Azure portal. I have set the config option to enable them and can verify that they can both be found in the `CurrentUser` 'My' store. My problem is now that one of them is failing validation. On my local machine I have this cert installed in the Trusted People store of `LocalMachine`. Is there anything I can with Azure to make this work?

Is the location of the cert the issue or is it possibly something with the certificate itself?

**Note that this is an app service, not a cloud service

Comment: Hi! Did you manage to fix the problem? I have exactly the same issue.

Comment: @kord Please check the solution below. Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

There are few things you can check, In Azure check in the app settings whether you have added your certificate. Its in the SSL section of you Azure app.

Another workaround would be where you are configuring your Token Authentication, you could set this settings.
For e.g. In my case, I was getting X509 Certificate error. 
I added this code in my project.

```
        System.IdentityModel.Configuration.IdentityConfiguration config = new System.IdentityModel.Configuration.IdentityConfiguration();
        config.CertificateValidator = X509CertificateValidator.None;
        config.CertificateValidationMode = X509CertificateValidationMode.None;
```

Basically turn off your validation. Most of the times, what happens is your local machine as all the certificates installed by an IT Operation person, but Those certificates are not on Azure.

You can check here for some reference as well. [Microsoft Certificate Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-custom-ssl)

Comment: Thanks Akshay. I have the certificate added. I am able to see it in the Azure's Kudu Powershell Console when I navigate to "cert:\CurrentUser\My". The problem is that I need it in "cert:\CurrentUser\TrustedPeople" since I use it to communicate with an on-premise WCF service (PeerTrust mode). So far, in Azure App Service world, I didn't find a way to install it in TrustedPeople store...

Comment: You can put that in required folder through KUDU or you can modify your csproj file

Comment: I think you can't do it for Azure App Services. 
`PS Cert:\CurrentUser> $destStore = Get-Item cert:\CurrentUser\TrustedPeople
PS Cert:\CurrentUser> $destStore.Open([System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.OpenFlags]::ReadWrite)
Exception calling "Open" with "1" argument(s): "Access is denied."`